# How to prevent sql injection without prepared statement?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I need to prevent sql injection in web application. Is there any way to prevent the same as I can not make changes in the whole application.

Comment: The way to prevent SQL injection is to not construct your own SQL statements. Instead use a robust and tested mechanism to construct them for you. This could be Prepared Statements, or stored procedures, or an ORM like Hibernate, but please, please, please, use something! Don't try and do it yourself - you *WILL* do it wrong.

Comment: So let me get this straight, you can modify the application to 'prevent sql injection', but you can't modify the application to use prepared statements, which are the best way to prevent sql injection.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes just want to know the best possible way to prevent sql injection it seems that prepared statement would be the best solution

Answer (score 0):

A possible answer without prepared statement is check if in the field are present certain "key words and symbols" and deny the possibilities to insert them, for example:

```
+
,
"
select
delete
table
drop
merge
union
all
dual
group
by
having
```

ect...

Comment: You should probably note that this is a terrible idea - it is *incredibly* hard to capture all the edge cases that can permit SQL injection. The correct answer is to just use prepared statements.

Comment: of course, but he said "without prepared statement"

Comment: If someone asks "How do I shoot myself in the foot with a gun without it hurting", the answer is "Don't do that!", rather than "Try using smaller bullets".

Comment: it could be a good point...but there must be a reason because someone want shoot his foot!

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's asking out of ignorance (I don't mean to be rude by saying that - I just mean that he is not sufficiently educated on SQL injection attacks). It's got to be our job as responsible community members to educate him out of an approach that is universally rejected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i just want to save time to prevent sql injection in application as prepared statement is not used properly in application and i have to made lot of changes for the same throughout the application.But it seems prepared statement would be the best solution for same.

Comment: @RB. Come on people. It's NOT always the case that the entire code base is in your control. There will be cases where you have to do that simply because the existing unchangeable code doesn't use prepared statement. There could be other reasons too.

Comment: @supertonsky If he's controlling the construction of the SQL statement with sufficient control to perform white/blacklisting, then he can almost certainly use prepared statements instead. The only time I can think of where that would not be the case is if there was some sort of *spit*in-house framework*spit* that he had to use - in which case he should raise the **serious** security concerns with his superiors. Security is **NOT** an optional feature for a web-application.

Comment: @RB. I exactly know where you're coming from but you can't rule out that there will be cases where you will need to employ tactical temporary fix while waiting for the opportunity to fix the real problem and that's why we are seeing these kinds of questions. We don't always work in an ideal workplace or environment, do we? The fact that a tactical temporary fix has to be sometimes employed instead of waiting also proves that we're not simply shrugging off the importance of security.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wide variety of ways to solve this and unfortunately each one of them will require you to make some changes to your web application. For reference the [OWASP guide](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) provides 3 examples of how you can reduce SQL Injection vulnerabilities

- Prepared Statements
- Stored Procedures
- Escaping user supplied input

Of these the Prepared Statement approach is the most likely to be successful with the Escaping the user input the most frail solution.